# Visual Studio 2013 datagridview without dataset

Tags: database, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a very simple problem in Visual Studio 2013, (C#) that I want to send to R using R.NET.  Just a little data, that I want to display in a table, then send to R.  Is it possible to load data into a datagridview without having it bound to a formal SQL dataset?  I'll get the data in a ascii flat file (.csv), so I'd like just read the file into an array, and copy the array to the datagridview.  Possible?

thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you'll need an object array of sorts like this

```
        Person p = new Person("abc");
        Person p2 = new Person("xyz");

        ArrayList A = new ArrayList();
        A.Add(p);
        A.Add(p1);

        GridView1.DataSource = A;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible to use whatever object as a data source for a `DataGridView`. Actually, any `IEnumerable` will do. A good option is to bind directly to a domain class (or a DTO or ViewModel or whatever), then assign each column source to match properties in that class.